# Recover from an unmountable_boot_volume BSOD

Tags: boot, windows-8.1

My windows 8.1 laptop is completely fried and I'm writing this on my phone. Last night I wanted to make a partition on my 1tb drive to install Ubuntu. So I clicked on my main C partition in disk manager and clicked "shrink". The idea was to shrink it down to about 600gb, leaving 300gb raw unallocated and the remaining 100gb (maybe less) dedicated to recovery partitions.

I set this up and then clicked the button to make disk manager start creating this partition. Now here's where I did something stupid. Disc manager just hung. No progress bar, nothing, whenever I hovered over it my cursor changed to the blue loading swirl.

I waited maybe 5-10 minutes of this and then I clicked drive manager's quit cross. To my credit I didn't force quit, I just wanted a response from the program. Surprisingly it quit instantly. And I think that action was what corrupted my drive and rendered my boot disk unbootable.

But anyway, I reopened disk manager and everything looked fine. My boot drive was partitioned, 600gb NTFS, 300gb raw unallocated. Windows was working perfectly too. I even formatted this 300gb partition to NTFS and called it "Ubuntu" and labelled it E no problem. I set it off formatting overnight and in the morning disk manager had finished formatting and windows was working no problem.

I plugged my Ubuntu installer pen drive ready to install ubuntu to E. I restarted holding down shift to get into UEFI bios. I entered the UEFI bios no problem. I clicked "bootable usb devices" with a view to booting my ubuntu pendrive. The UEFI bios restarted automatically.

And here's what happens now whenever I turn my laptop on:

```
1) Toshiba logo comes up
2) Blue screen of death and automatic restart
3) Repeat 1 and 2
4) Toshiba logo comes up with "preparing automatic repair"
5) Black screen for all time
```

The blue screen of death says the problem is:

UNMOUNTABLE_BOOT_VOLUME

I got into the traditional bios, put usb devices at the top of the boot order but it didn't boot my pendrive. The steps above occured.

I have a 32gb pen drive and my friend's windows 7 desktop at my disposal. Sadly no windows install disk though I do have a usb dvd burner and reader.

Please help me boot back into windows 8.1 :( id really love some command to fix my corrupt disk. Lots of precious data on my Ubuntu VM I wanted to transfer into my physical Ubuntu partition. Windows was working flawlessly all night last night. it only packed in after a restart. Surely all is not lost?

Awesome answer will let me boot windows back up as though I never partitioned.

Good answer will tell me how to recover my data.

Im an idiot for not backing up I know.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check (with any disk management tool like "diskpart.exe" or with Linux gparted) that following partitions exist on hard disk:

1. EFI System partition - 100-500 MB
2. Microsoft Reserved partition - exactly 128 MB
3. Windows partition

You can [download Windows 8.1 and create USB/DVD media using Media creation tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media).
Then use recovery - Automatic Repair.

If repair cannot fix problem try using bcdboot.exe:

```
bcdboot N:\windows /s Q:
```

where N: is partition where Windows is installed and Q: is mapped to EFI System partition. Change drive letters in example command to reflect your mappings.

For installing Ubuntu it is better to delete "Ubuntu" partition you have created and leave it as not partitioned free space on disk and let Ubuntu create partitions(ext4+swap) for its installation (select option install Ubuntu alongside Windows during setup)